# How to check if an excel file is locked for editing

Tags: excel, powershell

How would I check to see if the file is locked for editing in excel? I have tried try catch but that doesn't capture it. The display alert itself won't even show if I run it in PowerShell. It will show a read only file after it failed to save.

```
$file = 'path'

$excl = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'
try {
  $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
}
catch {
  Exit
}

$excl.DisplayAlerts = $TRUE
$excl.visible=$TRUE

try {
    $wrkb.Save()
}
catch {
  Exit
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992975/4276928

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).